# Windows 7, cannot receive multitouch events on two different controls

Tags: mfc, windows-7, multi-touch

I have Win 7 OS on my machine and have Multi-touch capable monitor which supports up to 2 simultaneous touches.

I have created MFC Dialog application with two sliders and am trying to move them simultaneously with two fingers, but can only move one slider. If I touch the dialog box with two fingers then it receives two touches but two different sliders don't receive simultaneous touches.

On MS Paint I can draw using two fingers.

I also tried to search for multitouch application involving more than one controls but could not find any, and I am starting to wonder if its possible at all on Windows 7

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need not only your OS to support multi-touch, but your controls too. Have you done the Hands on Labs for MFC and Multitouch? http://channel9.msdn.com/learn/courses/Windows7/Multitouch has several Native and MFC examples.

If you don't have a real need in your app for two sliders moving at once, but were just trying it out, try something a little different, like zooming by pinching or panning by dragging two fingers, rotating etc. If you want multiple independent touches (ie not interpreted as a pinch zoom) the source code for games is your best examples.

Comment: Hi Kate, Thanks for the link.

Comment: Thanks Kate. Actually I need to move two sliders simultaneously. I have tried the Paint example and it works fine but the case of 2 sliders doesn't work. I believe that in case of paint its just one controller receiving touch event, and in my case there are two sliders that I want to move. Only one slider receives touch event even if I try to move both simultaneously. Also one slider does receive two touches. Please let me know if you know about any example which has more than one controller that can be touched simultaneously please let me know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

if using WPF is feasible, the "Surface Toolkit for Windows Touch" provides a full suite of touch optimized controls that can be used simultaneously.

you could perhaps host the WPF controls inside your MFC UI but be aware that all of the WPF controls would need to be in a single hwnd - Win7 has an OS limitation that multitouch can only be done with one hwnd at a time.

Comment: Thanks Robert for you reply. I will definitely try your suggestion.